Deleting vs. Disabling an option
I am wondering what the difference between deleting and disabling an option is? I would like to clean up the option field drop down menu to only reflect the ones we would like to continue using without deleting or affecting any of the historical options associated with the ones we are planning to disable.
When I tried Disable got that message :
"Are you sure you want to disable the 'xxx' option ?
WARNING - Disabling an option which has been assigned to existing records will result in that option being cleared when the record is edited."
Thanks for your help.

This is an ongoing issue. There is a split opinion in how it should work. See
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14240#issuecomment-496791671 for some discussion.
